# Join query to delete a record both in child class and parent class

Tags: sql, join, informix

I need to delete a record in both child table and parent table with the reference to another column.The primary key of one table is equal to foreign key of another table.eg.table A.pkid=table B.fkid

How do I use join query or cascade to delete it.
I tried couple of queries but it shows invalid syntax.

```
delete from 
table A table B where pkid=(SELECT fk_id from table B) 
where name='SEP' from table B

delete from 
table A join table B ON table A.fk_id=(SELECT pk_id FROM table B) 
where name='SEP' from table B

delete from 
table A join table B ON A.fk_id=B.pk_id 
where name='SEP' from table B
```

Could you please refine my query or give me a link where I can get some help on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which database? Add an example with the sample result set

Comment: informix database.    original query that I used.                                                                           delete from table dev join phone ON device.fkphonetemplate=(select pkid from phonetemplate) where name='SEP64A0E7F70005-SIP-Individual Template' from phonetemplate;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you need is something simple:

```
BEGIN WORK;

DELETE FROM A WHERE fk_id IN (SELECT pk_id FROM B WHERE name = 'SEP');
DELETE FROM B WHERE name = 'SEP';

COMMIT WORK;
```

The alternative is to [define the PK-FK relationship](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0304.htm) in the schema with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, and children will be automatically deleted on deletion of the parent.